# Poco Net : How to register clients?

Tags: c++, networking, poco

Help me please with a few questions about Poco:

- Can't understand how can I organize new connections in a std::map for example?
- Is there keep_alive functionality for TCP?
- May be You know some complex articles about Poco::Net?

```
class ServerConnection : public Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection
{
   //...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const auto address = Poco::Net::SocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 61300);
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket srv_socket(address);
    Poco::Net::TCPServer srv(new Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactoryImpl<ServerConnection>(), srv_socket, params);
    srv.start();
    while (1);
```

Have found this variant, but I want to use TCPServer tools:

```
while (true)
{
    if (srv_socket.poll(span, Socket::SELECT_READ))
    {
        Poco::Net::StreamSocket strs = srv_socket.acceptConnection();
        Poco::Net::SocketStream socket_stream(srv_socket);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjhx8b049j6AhWS_CoKHc9iA98QFnoECA4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3QVCTSQ1NCbkjRrQ_Z5c2o

Here is several good examples of using Poco net library

Comment: Already red it. Unfortunately didn't really helped: they are very simple. It's just a bouquet